# Correct use of "three.module.js"?

Tags: javascript, module, three.js

i am trying to learn how to use modules. I thought I would start with the simplest possible but already then I have the problem that it doesn't want to run. I have to overlook something important but I just don't see what.
Including "three.module.js" or executing the script as "module" does not work.
Does anyone have a working example?
I got this example from:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_cube

Why doesn't that work if I do it locally

```
<script type="module">

    import * as THREE from "lib/three.module.js";
            
    var camera, scene, renderer;            
    var mesh;
            
    init();         
    animate();
            
    function init() {
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );                
        camera.position.z = 400;
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );                
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00}); 
                
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );                
        scene.add( mesh );
                
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );       
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );              
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );      
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
    }
            
    function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;             
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    }
            
    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;               
        mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share the specific errors you are seeing in the JS console when trying this code? Your code looks fine, and the example you link to is a working example, so there may be something wrong with your complete HTML file or how you're hosting the code locally.

Comment: Does it work, if you use `import * as THREE from "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js"`?

Comment: I have tested your proposal, then it will work again.
So it makes a difference from where i include "three.module.js". Where's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have researched intensively for the last two days. "export / import" only works via http and not with local directories. So you have to set up your own server. The alternative that I am currently using is a bundler. Parcel is not compatible with my tablet but webpack works very well. To do this, I first had to install a terminal. I chose termux. Then I installed node.js (v12.18.3) via termux and then webpack. At first it seemed like a big effort to me, but after you've done it all once, it doesn't seem that bad anymore. Important point! Termux must be configured in the app manager on android in order to have access to the sdcard in the device. By default, access is forbidden and the command line then shows "permission denied" if you want to access the internal memory with "cd /sdcard/".

I created the project normaly with an editor, you don't need the terminal for that. termux is then only required to run webpack with "npx webpack" after going to the project directory in termux.

My first example:

```
//path-structure

webpack-demo
|
|_page.html
|_webpack.config.js
|_src
   |_index.js
   |_bar.js
```

```
//page.html
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
<head>  </head> 
<body> 
<div id="message"></div> 
<script src="dist/bundle.js"></script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

```
//webpack.config.js
const path = require('path'); 
module.exports = { 
//mode: 'development',
mode: 'production',
entry: './src/index.js', 
output: { path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), 
filename: 'bundle.js' } 
};
```

```
//index.js
import bar from './bar'; 
bar();
```

```
//bar.js
export default function bar() { 
 
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

Software source:

termux: install from google play

node.js: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

webpack: https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/

now I am satisfied, because now I can write properly structured javascript code